# Parsing 'Nach der Mitte zu stieg sie an wie ein Kuppeldach'

Tags: grammar, meaning, german-to-english

I think I understand the meaning of this sentence, but I don't understand how it's constructed.

I'm assuming *ansteigen* (to rise) is the verb, and *ein Kuppeldach* (a dome) is the subject and *Nach der Mitte* means 'towards the middle', but I don't understand the role of the words *zu*, *sie* or *wie*.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: What the hell... Is this a German sentence? - *Das versteht kein Schwein*...

Comment: @Em1: The verb gives you orientation: Split into 3 pieces `Nach der Mitte zu`|`stieg sie an`|`wie ein Kuppeldach`, and that may help you to understand the structure

Comment: @Em1: _Nach ... zu_ ist sehr literarisch (oder regional?), ansonsten geht's. Das Buch hat übrigens den Deutschen Jugendbuchpreis erhalten; es ist aber auch schon vierzig Jahre alt.

Comment: @chirlu: 40 Jahre schon? Verdammt ... ;-)

Comment: Es ist schon sehr traurig, wenn ein Satz von Muttersprachlern nicht mehr verstanden wird, nur weil eine Konstruktion [etwas älter](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nach+der+Mitte+zu%2Czur+Mitte+hin&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=) ist oder aus einer anderen Region stammt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subject is *sie* (referring to something before that sentence).

*Nach ... zu* is a somewhat unusual synonym of *zu ... hin*; your translation "towards the middle" is fine (but consumes the *zu* as well).

*Wie* means "like". It introduces a description (by comparison) of the way in which the whatever rises: "like a dome".

Comment: [Some additional data.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nach+der+Mitte+zu%2Czur+Mitte+hin&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=)